# Why is the page design for search results different than questions/tagged results?

Tags: discussion, tags, design, search, user-interface

For example, check out [stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)

[image]

as compared to [stackoverflow.com/search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpandas%5D&searchOn=3)

[image]

Personally, I find the */search* version much less visually pleasing. (I am curious if others agree.) Is there a reason these aren't standardized to look more similar?

---

I guess my question wasn’t clear based on the comment & answer.. here are some specific questions.

1. why are search results contained in a box with margins on both sides but recent questions aren’t?
2. why do recent question results show user thumbnails but search results don’t?

I feel like these pages should present data in a more consistent manner.

Comment: Search includes both questions and answers, whereas the tagged questions are just questions.

Comment: The box is because you're also a member of a team I think. Search runs in public and on your team, both get their separate box so you dont mistakenly post private stuff as an answer to a public question. This is also indicated by the "All" to the left of your search bar